# Invalid method declaration, return type required

Tags: java

I am getting an error at public Rectangle(double width, double height){ saying that it's an invalid method declaration, return type required.  I'm not sure how to fix it.  These are also my instructions for my assignment:
Write a super class encapsulating a rectangle. A rectangle has two attributes representing the width and the height of the rectangle. It has methods returning the perimeter and the area of the rectangle. This class has a subclass, encapsulating a parallelepiped, or box.  A parallelepiped has a rectangle as its base, and another attribute, its length. It has two methods that calculate and return its area and volume.

```
`public class Rectangle1
{

private double width;
private double height;

public Rectangle1(){
}

public Rectangle(double width, double height){
this.width = width;
this.height = height;

}

public double getWidth(){
return width;
}

public void setWidth(double width) {
this.width = width;

}


public double getHeight(){
return height;

}

public void setHeight(double height){
this.height = height;

}

public double getArea(){
return width * height;
}

public double getPerimeter(){
return 2 * (width + height);

}

}



public class TestRectangle {

public static void main(String[] args) {

Rectangle1 rectangle = new Rectangle1(2,4);

System.out.println("\nA rectangle " + rectangle.toString());
System.out.println("The area is " + rectangle.getArea());
System.out.println("The perimeter is " +
rectangle.getPerimeter());
}
}`
```

Comment: Please indent your code properly. No one wants to read this, except he's bored to death.

Comment: Also, don't include code / text not relevant to the problem you're facing. If you're getting a compiler error, the error message and the method where the error occurs is enough.

Comment: @Brett - this isn't a forum for us to do your school assignment for you - try to limit it to a specific question/problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Constructor** name should be same as your **class name**. your class name is `Rectangle1` thus your `Constructor name` should be the **same** as well, currently **java compiler** this it as an **method without a return type**, thus it **complains**.

```
public Rectangle(double width, double height){
```

should be

```
public Rectangle1(double width, double height){
```

Comment: Rectangle1.java:52: error: class TestRectangle is public, should be declared in a file named TestRectangle.java
public class TestRectangle {
       ^
1 error

Comment: @BrettSteen It's bad form to move the goalposts by adding new questions through edits/comments. You should ideally try and solve the new problem yourself instead of just trying to get whoever pays attention to your post to guide you through your whole assignment.

Comment: @BrettSteen You can only have one `public` class per file. Make a new file for `TestRectangle`, or move `main` into `Rectangle1`.

Comment: Move class TestRectangle to its own file as suggested by the error message

Comment: @millimoose Sorry, first time asking a question here.  Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: @BrettSteen as daniel Fischer said, you cant have more than one public class per a file. make the class whcih you are executing the program as a public class i.e.,the class whcih has your main method :)