# Java - Invalid Method Declaration; Return Type Required for a method

Tags: java, compiler-errors

My Problem is in two different programs for an assignment.  One assignment is to write the document to a file, the second assignment part is to read from a file.  I get the same error in both cases.  I am not entirely sure what I am doing wrong.  Please forgive my Nooby nature.

HERE IS THE WRITE CODE

```
//WriteContactsAssignment: A program to enter contact information to be written to a Contacts file
//Author: Daniel Golightly
//Date: February 26, 2014

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.Dialog;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.lang.System.*;

public class WriteContacts extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{   
    //GUI COMPONENTS
    JLabel nameLabel;
    JLabel ageLabel;
    JLabel emailLabel;
    JLabel phoneLabel;
    JTextField nameField;
    JTextField ageField;
    JTextField emailField;
    JTextField phoneField;
    JButton btnWrite;
    JPanel panelWrite;

    //VARIABLES FOR WRITING
    String name;
    String email;
    String phone;
    String ageString; //holds age to be converted to integer for verifying
    int age; //variable for age after conversion to integer for verifying

    //CONSTRUCTOR FOR FILE WRITING
    public static void writeToFile(String textToWrite)
    {
        final String outputPath = "ContactsFile.txt";
        try
        {
            FileWriter contactWriter = new FileWriter(outputPath);
            contactWriter.write(textToWrite);
            contactWriter.close();
        }
        catch (IOException ex2)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame,
            "The file did not create properly",
            "Oops!", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }
    }

    //GUI CONSTRUCTOR
    public WriteContacts2()
    {
        setUndecorated(false);//GUI GUI GUI GUI GUI GUI GUI GUI GUI GUI GUI GUI GUI GUI GUI GUI GUI GUI GUI GUI
        setResizable(false);
        setSize(400, 200);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setTitle("Contact Writer");

        GridLayout fieldsLayout = new GridLayout(5, 2, 10, 10);

        panelWrite = new JPanel();
        panelWrite.setLayout(fieldsLayout);

        nameLabel = new JLabel("Name: ");
        panelWrite.add(nameLabel);
        nameField = new JTextField(30);
        panelWrite.add(nameField);
        ageLabel = new JLabel("Age: ");
        panelWrite.add(ageLabel);
        ageField = new JTextField(2);
        panelWrite.add(ageField);
        phoneLabel = new JLabel("Phone Number: ");
        panelWrite.add(phoneLabel);
        phoneField = new JTextField(10);
        panelWrite.add(phoneField);
        emailLabel = new JLabel("Email: ");
        panelWrite.add(emailLabel);
        emailField = new JTextField(50);
        panelWrite.add(emailField);
        panelWrite.add(new JLabel(" "));
        btnWrite = new JButton("Submit");
        panelWrite.add(btnWrite);
        add(panelWrite);

        setVisible(true);
    }

    //VALIDATES ENTRY, WRITES TO FILE, CLEARS FIELDS FOR ADDITIONAL ENTRY
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {

        name = nameField.getText();
        email = emailField.getText();
        phone = phoneField.getText();
        ageString = ageField.getText();

        try
        {
            age = Integer.parseInt(ageString);
        }
        catch (NumberFormatException ex)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame,
            "The Age you entered is not a number",
            "Age Error",
            JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }

        if (0 > age || age > 120)
        {
            JOptionPane.ShowMessageDialog(frame,
            "The age you entered is invalid. Please enter between 1 and 120",
            "Age Error",
            JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }

        else if (ContactsFile.exists())
        {
            writeToFile("Name: " + name + "/n");
            writeToFile("E-Mail: " + email + "/n");
            writeToFile("Age: " + age + "/n");
            writeToFile("Phone Number: " + phone + "/n" + "/n");        
            //OPEN A FILE WRITER HERE TO WRITE TO THE NEXT LINE OF THE FILE, WRITING EACH VARIABLE TO A DIFFERENT LINE
            //LEAVE TWO BLANK LINES AT THE BOTTOM OF THE FILE
            //CLOSE THE WRITER
        }

        nameField.setText("");
        emailField.setText("");
        ageField.setText("");
        phoneField.setText("");
        //WRITE MESSAGE THAT WRITE WAS SUCCESSFUL
        //CLEAR ENTRY FIELDS
        //EXIT EVENT    
    }

    //MAIN ARGS
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        WriteContacts2 WriteGUI = new WriteContacts2();
    }
}
```

HERE IS THE READ CODE

```
//ReadContactsAssignment: A program to read contact information from a Contacts file
//Author: Daniel Golightly
//Date: February 26, 2014

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.text.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.lang.System.*;

public class ReadContacts extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{   
    //GUI COMPONENTS
    JLabel contactInfo;
    JTextArea displayArea;
    JButton btnRead;
    JPanel panelRead;

    //GUI CONSTRUCTOR
    public ReadContacts2 ()
    {
        setUndecorated(false);      //GUI GUI GUI GUI GUI GUI GUI GUI GUI GUI GUI GUI GUI GUI GUI GUI GUI GUI GUI GUI
        setSize(450, 600);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setTitle("Contact List");

        GridLayout readLayout = new GridLayout(2, 1);

        panelRead = new JPanel();
        panelRead.setLayout(readLayout);

        displayArea = new JTextArea();
        panelRead.add(displayArea);
        btnRead = new JButton("Read Contacts");
        panelRead.add(btnRead); 

        add(panelRead);

        setVisible(true);
    }

    //READS THE CONTACTS.TXT FILE TO THE TEXTAREA
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        File ContactsFile = File("Week3Contacts.txt");
        ContactsFile.createNewFile("Week3Contacts.txt", false).close();

        try //OR SOMETHING VERY SIMILAR
        {
            if(ContactsFile.exists())
            {
                FileReader reader = new FileReader( "Week3Contacts.txt" );
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(reader);
                edit.read( br, null );
                br.close();
                edit.requestFocus();
            }
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException ex)
        {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame,
        "The file could not be found or is corrupted. Contact your IT administrator.",
        "Oops", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }
        //VALIDATE THAT THE FILE EXISTS
        //IF FILE VALIDATION FAILS, DISPLAY FILE NOT FOUND, CONTACT ADMIN MESSAGE
        //OTHERWISE CONTINUE EVENT
        //OPEN READER AND READ TO THE TEXTAREA
        //CLOSE THE READER TO KEEP IT FROM EATING RESOURCES AND ALLOW THE FILE TO BE INTERACTED WITH
        //EXIT EVENT    
    }

    //MAIN ARGS
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        ReadContacts2 ReadGUI = new ReadContacts2();
    }
}
```

I also apologize for the excess comments, some of which make no sense at all, as I have since changed my code.  I am willing to repost the code if needed. I do not generally ask for help with assignments, but since this is crucial to my grade and I feel I am on the cusp of having completed this assignment, I though it may be okay to ask for some guidance.  Thanks.

Comment: Search for the error message. You'll find duplicates.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13483629/invalid-method-declaration-return-type-required , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15698239/java-invalid-method-declaration-return-type-required

Answer (score 1):

You have a class name `WriteContacts` but you're trying to create a constructor with name `public WriteContacts2()` which is not valid. Constructor name should exactly match the class name.

Either change your class name to `WriteContacts2` or change the invalid constructor from:

```
public WriteContacts2() { // }
```

to

```
public WriteContacts() { // }
```

Same applies for your `ReadContacts` class also.